# Create Typeform in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have made a typeform and it looks like http://prntscr.com/kwxkv9.
My question is can it be done like this http://prntscr.com/kwxlbj. Please do suggest if you have any solutions. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the theme of your typeform, select colors, background and images. It's all explained [here](https://www.typeform.com/help/apply-a-theme-to-your-typeform/) on Typeform Help Center.

Then you can embed your form on your website using the Embed code Typeform gives you. Also explained on [Typeform Help Center](https://www.typeform.com/help/embed-a-typeform/)

Hope it works well for you